# Android Beacon Library detecting iBeacon fails! not fair :(

Tags: android, bluetooth, ibeacon-android

I try to use the Android Beacon Library to detect iBeacons but it doesn't work.

The output from the logcat ist just:

`I/SELinux﹕ Function: selinux_android_load_priority [0], There is no sepolicy file.
I/SELinux﹕ Function: selinux_android_load_priority , spota verifySig and checkHash pass. priority version is VE=SEPF_GT-I9195_4.4.2_0046
I/SELinux﹕ selinux_android_seapp_context_reload: seapp_contexts file is loaded from /data/security/spota/seapp_contexts
E/dalvikvm﹕ >>>>> Normal User
E/dalvikvm﹕ >>>>> com.cyberland.felix.ibeaconexample [ userId:0 | appId:10176 ]
D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
I/PersonaManager﹕ getPersonaService() name persona_policy
D/BeaconParser﹕ Parsing beacon layout: m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25
D/BeaconParser﹕ Parsing beacon layout: m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24
W/ModelSpecificDistanceCalculator﹕ Cannot find match for this device.  Using default
W/ModelSpecificDistanceCalculator﹕ Cannot find match for this device.  Using default
E/MonitoringStatus﹕ Deserialization exception, message: $s`

And then just

`D/BluetoothAdapter﹕ stopLeScan()`

again and again...

I just modified the example from the oficial page:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements BeaconConsumer {
protected static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
private BeaconManager beaconManager;
private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION = 1;

private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    /*
    mBluetoothAdapter = ((BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE)).getAdapter();
    mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Scanned BLE device with mac: " + device.getAddress());
        }
    });
     */
    beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
    beaconManager.bind(this);




}


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    beaconManager.unbind(this);

}


@Override
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
    beaconManager.setRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
        @Override
        public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
            if (beacons.size() > 0) {
                Log.i(TAG, "The first beacon I see is about " + beacons.iterator().next().getDistance() + " meters away.");
            }
        }
    });

    try {
        beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myRangingUniqueId", null, null, null));
    } catch (RemoteException e) {    }
}
```

I hope you can help me!

Best regards,
Felix

Comment: What version of Android does your phone have?  What do you see if you go to Settings -> Location?  Is location on or off, and what mode is it in -- high accuracy, device only, or battery saving?

Comment: The phone has 4.4.2 (Samsung S4 Mini), Location is high accuracy. I could find the iBeacon with an app from the playstore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem may have to do with the proper permissions not being granted for scanning on your device.   In order to test this theory, please add the following code to the `onCreate` method of your main activity, and see what it returns.  An example output is shown below for what I see on my Nexus 5X.

```
        try {
            PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(this.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
            Log.d(TAG, "SDK "+Build.VERSION.SDK_INT+" App Permissions:");
            if (info.requestedPermissions != null) {
                for (String p : info.requestedPermissions) {
                    int grantResult = this.checkPermission(p, android.os.Process.myPid(), android.os.Process.myUid());
                    if (grantResult == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        Log.d(TAG, p+" PERMISSION_GRANTED");
                    }
                    else {
                        Log.d(TAG, p+" PERMISSION_DENIED: "+grantResult);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Cannot get permissions due to error", e);
        }
```

Example output:

```
04-17 12:04:01.943 30624-30624/? D/MonitoringActivity: SDK 23 App Permissions:
04-17 12:04:01.944 30624-30624/? D/MonitoringActivity: android.permission.INTERNET PERMISSION_GRANTED
04-17 12:04:01.945 30624-30624/? D/MonitoringActivity: android.permission.BLUETOOTH PERMISSION_GRANTED
04-17 12:04:01.945 30624-30624/? D/MonitoringActivity: android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN PERMISSION_GRANTED
04-17 12:04:01.946 30624-30624/? D/MonitoringActivity: android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED PERMISSION_GRANTED
04-17 12:04:01.946 30624-30624/? D/MonitoringActivity: android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION PERMISSION_GRANTED
```

If you see any of the above permissions missing from the output on your device, the solution may be to manually add `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` location permissions to your AndroidManifest.xml.  If you are seeing PERMISSION_DENIED, it may be a different problem.  You could skip the permissions check before starting beacon scanning on your device, which would be possible by temporarily downgrading your version of the Android Beacon Library to 2.7 that does not do this check.

Comment: Are you saying that permission was missing from your debug output?  Or are you saying it said the permission was DENIED?  Also, are you using Android Studio or Eclipse?    Sorry for the follow-ups, but I would like to understand exactly what problem you had and how you fixed it so I can help others.

Comment: The permission was missing and I'm using Android Studio. I had the same problem with Eclipsed. Adding ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission to the manifest solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, the official example (android-beacon-library-reference) produces the same output. I can't explain that.